# Facebook PHP image

Tags: php, image, facebook

I've serached a little but I didn't find anything that could solve my problem.

I've managed to post on page as page admin, link is added correctly, but image isn't attached. My code:

```
Blahblah authentication, etc.

        $attachment = array(
            'message' => 'text',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'link' => 'http://somelink.com',
            'description' => '',
            'access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN
        );

        if(something) $attachment['media'] = array(array('type'=>'image', 'src'=>'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/media/file/image_by_id/".$data['thumb_file_tree_id'].'/?w=400&h=500', 'href'=>'http://somelink.com'));


        try {
            if($facebook->api('/XXX/feed', 'post', $attachment))
            {
                echo 'Hooray, ok';
            }
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo 'Damn';
        }
```

Result: Correctly posted news with link ('Hooray, ok'), but without image. Can it be due to PHP generated image, and not png/jpg/gif extension? I've added some additional headers like etag, accepted-ranges, last modified, etc. What am I doing wrong (again)?

'Something' is true, checked with print_r whole attachment array.

E: Again removed [0]

Comment: Rather than ask if it can be due to that, eliminate it. Replace that image with the URL to a static file and see if anything changes. Also, is $attachment['media'] supposed to be an array containing a single element which is another array?

Comment: Checked with normal image - doesn't work either. Yes, it has to be like this. Also added $attachment>>[0]<<['media']. So, what's wrong now?

Comment: I'm not sure `echo 'Damn';` qualifies as beneficial error handling.

Comment: I simplified everything here, there's exception further rethrowing.

Comment: `echo 'Damn';` is a waaaaay cleaner error msg than the four-letter words I usually use :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just attach an image, you can use the picture key in your attachment.

```
$attachment = array(
            'message' => 'text',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'link' => 'http://somelink.com',
            'description' => '',
            'access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
            'picture' => 'http://example.com/example.jpg'
);
```